# Unable to push metrics in prometheus

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I am trying to push metrics in `Prometheus` using `Pushgateway` but not able to complete the task.
This is the code:

```
var  client = require('prom-client');
var gateway = new client.Pushgateway('http://localhost:9091');
gateway.pushAdd({ jobName: 'test', group : "production" }, function(err, resp, body){

});
```

Prometheus config:

```
scrape_interval:     15s 
evaluation_interval: 15s 

external_labels:
      monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'example-random'
    scrape_interval: 5s

static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:8080', 'localhost:8081']
    labels:
      group: 'production'

  - targets: ['localhost:8082']
    labels:
      group: 'canary'

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'test '
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9091']
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Prometheus configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a few problems with your prometheus config - check out the Prometheus github repo [example](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/config/testdata/conf.good.yml) and the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/) for future reference.

One issue is that you have multiple `scrape_configs`. 
You can only have one `scrape_configs` in your configuration for Prometheus.

Another issue is that each job can only have one `static_configs`.

The rest is mainly due to incorrect formatting.

The edited config below should work for you now:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'production'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080', 'localhost:8081']
        labels:
          group: 'production'

  - job_name: 'canary'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8082']
        labels:
          group: 'canary'

  - job_name: 'test'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9091']
```

It's also important to note that the metrics from the Pushgateway are not pushed to Prometheus. Prometheus is pull based and will pull the metrics from the Pushgateway itself. The metrics the [Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) collects are pushed to it by ephemeral and batch jobs.

Comment: Still I am able to see the jobs created in Pushgateway but unable to query on those metrics in Prometheus. So may be prometheus is not able to pull it from Pushgateway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the URL from http to https and try as follows:

```
var  client = require('prom-client');
var gateway = new client.Pushgateway('https://localhost:9091');
gateway.pushAdd({ jobName: 'test', group : "production" }, function(err, 
                 resp, body){
                });
```